# Bounty expired before I received an email

Tags: discussion, bounty

I put a bounty on this question: [Command line performance testing tool for JavaScript](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69695/command-line-performance-testing-tool-for-javascript)

An hour ago I recieved this email:

> Reminder: Your Bounty Ended!
>
> Your bounty on the question … Command line performance testing tool for JavaScript … ended and will be auto-closed after the 24-hour grace period expires.
>
> Thanks for putting a bounty on your question. It looks like there are still no answers yet. You should consider improving your question to attract more answers. Could you… … add more text describing the problem? … add or change the tags? … update the title to more accurately reflect the issue?
>
> Once you get answers, please review them.
>
> If you feel one of them deserves your bounty, award it by clicking the bounty icon to the left of the answer. Otherwise, you might consider providing feedback in the form of comments or edits. If you *don’t* award your bounty, the highest scored answer (with a minimum of 2 score) provided after your bounty started may be automatically awarded half the bounty amount.
>
> For more information, refer to the bounty faq.

Someone has since answered the question - but I can't award the bounty.

Is this because I have received the email too late, or is a bug on (or perhaps a feature) on the question being applied after the bounty expired?

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  My understanding is that once the bounty expires, it cannot be awarded to answers posted after the bounty period.